# Borrar renglones de un csv Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

Con el siguiente codigo convierto un XLSX en CSV. Necesito borrar los primeros 10 renglones de el csv resultante. Como podria hacerlo?

```
# encoding=utf8
import sys
import xlrd
import csv

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xlsx')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()

# runs the csv_from_excel function:
csv_from_excel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de borrar simplemente no guardes las filas que no quieres en el csv. simplemente usa `range` adecuadamente para ello. Para ignorar las primeras 10 filas basta con:

```
for rownum in range(10, sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

Si la primera fila de tu xlsx fuera en realidad la cabecera y quieres que sea pasada al csv, puedes hacer:

```
wr.writerow(sh.row_values(0))
for rownum in range(11, sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
```